# Why can't I use istream_view and std::accumulate to sum up my input?

Tags: c++, c++20, accumulate, std-ranges

This program:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto rng = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(std::cin);
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng), 0);
}
```

is supposed to sum up all integers appearing as text on the standard input stream. But - it doesn't compile. I know `std::ranges::begin()` and `std::ranges::end()` exist, so what's going on? The compiler tells me it can't find a suitable candidate; why?

Answer (score 11):

From inception up through C++17, everything in `<algorithm>` is based on iterator pairs: you have one `iterator` referring to the beginning of a range and one `iterator` referring to the end of the range, always having the same type.

In C++20, this was generalized. A range is now denoted by an `iterator` and a `sentinel` for that iterator - where the `sentinel` itself need not actually be an iterator of any kind, it just needs to be a type that can compare equal to its corresponding iterator (this is the [`sentinel_for`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.sentinel) concept).

C++17 ranges tend to be<sup>†</sup> valid C++20 ranges, but not necessarily in the opposite direction. One reason is the ability to have a distinct `sentinel` type, but there are others, which also play into this question (see below).

To go along with the new model, C++20 added a large amount of algorithms into the `std::ranges` namespace that take an `iterator` and a `sentinel`, rather than two `iterator`s. So for instance, while we've always had:

```cpp
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  constexpr InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                               const T& value);
```

we now also have:

```cpp
namespace ranges {
  template<input_­iterator I, sentinel_­for<I> S, class T, class Proj = identity>
    requires indirect_­binary_­predicate<ranges::equal_to, projected<I, Proj>, const T*>
    constexpr I find(I first, S last, const T& value, Proj proj = {});

  template<input_­range R, class T, class Proj = identity>
    requires indirect_­binary_­predicate<ranges::equal_to,
                                       projected<iterator_t<R>, Proj>, const T*>
    constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<R>
      find(R&& r, const T& value, Proj proj = {});
}
```

The first overload here takes an `iterator`/`sentinel` pair and the second takes a range instead.

---

While a lot of algorithms added corresponding overloads into `std::ranges`, the ones in `<numeric>` were left out. There is a `std::accumulate` but there is no `std::ranges::accumulate`. As such, the only version we have available at the moment is one that takes an iterator-pair. Otherwise, you could just write:

```cpp
auto rng = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(std::cin);
std::cout << std::ranges::accumulate(rng, 0);
```

Unfortunately, `std::ranges::istream_view` is one of the new, C++20 ranges whose sentinel type differs from its iterator type, so you cannot pass `rng.begin()` and `rng.end()` into `std::accumulate` either.

This leaves you with two options generally (three, if you include waiting for C++23, which will hopefully have a [`std::ranges::fold`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html)):

1. Write your own range-based and iterator-sentinel-based algorithms. Which for `fold` is very easy to do.

Or

2. There is a utility to wrap a C++20 range into a C++17-compatible one: `views::common`. So you could this:

```cpp
auto rng = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(ints) | std::views::common;
std::cout << std::accumulate(rng.begin(), rng.end(), 0);
```

Except not in this specific case.

`istream_view`'s iterators aren't copyable, and in C++17 all iterators must be. So there isn't really a way to provide C++17-compatible iterators based on `istream_view`. You need proper C++20-range support. The future `std::ranges::fold` will support move-only views and move-only iterators, but `std::accumulate` never can.

Which in this case, just leaves option 1.

---

<sup>†</sup>A C++20 iterator needs to be default-constructible, which was not a requirement of C++17 iterators. So a C++17 range with non-default-constructible iterators would not be a valid C++20 range.

Comment: "*Which in this case, just leaves option 1*" - or option 3: simply don't use `std::ranges::istream_view`, use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) instead, eg: `std::cout << std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), 0);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Meh. I'd still prefer 1. It's not even a dozen lines of code and is broadly useful. Plus, what if you want to sum the even numbers in the input? Or the squares of the input? Or ...

Comment: "Unfortunately, ... differs from its iterator type" <- This is not unfortunate in itself.

Comment: @einpoklum Given that it prevents you from doing what you want to do, I would classify it as unfortunate, yes. If you don't, that's fine, but don't go around editing people's answers because you have different preferences on word choice -- that's not what editing is for.

Comment: @Barry: But it doesn't, in itself, prevent me from doing what I want. I wouldn't make the sentinel into a proper iterator, I think, if I had the choice.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the end of a C++ range is *not*, in the general case, an iterator, but rather, a *sentinel*. A sentinel can have a different type than an iterator and admit fewer operations - as, generally speaking, you mostly need to compare against it to know you've reached the end of the range, and may not be allowed to just work with it like any iterator. For more about this distinction, read:

[What's the difference between a sentinel and an end iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900557/whats-the-difference-between-a-sentinel-and-an-end-iterator)

Now, standard-library algorithms (including the ones in `<numeric>`) take *pairs of iterators of the same type*. In your example:

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
constexpr T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

see? `InputIt` must be the type of both the beginning and end of the range. This can (probably) not even be "fixed" for the `istream_view` range, because the end of the standard input really isn't an iterator per se. (Although maybe you could bludgeon it into being an iterator and throw exceptions when doing irrelevant things with it.)

So, we would need either a new variant of `std::accumulate` or an `std::ranges::accumulate`, which we [currently don't have](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges). Or, of course, you could write that yourself, which should not be too difficult.

**Edit:** One last option, suggested by @RemyLebeau, is to use an `std::istream_iterator` instead:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
    std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
    0);
```